# User picture in teaser

Tags: users, media

I've added this code to show user picture under own post and it works perfectly but when i logged out , i cant see user picture !!??

```
<div class="user-pic">

            <?php
            $user = user_load($user->uid);
            if($user->picture){
                print theme_image_style(
                    array(
                        'style_name' => 'user-pic',
                        'path' => $user->picture->uri,
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'class' => 'avatar'
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Any advice ?

Comment: who will be the user when you will log out ?? you are displaying a user picture so it shows the picture of the logged in user. when you logged out the user becomes anonymous

Comment: i want to show it to everyone and it's public @Fahad

Comment: In that case you need to get the $account and not the $user

Comment: Just to elaborate. You are getting the uid of the currently logged in user, when you should get it of the account attached to the resource you are viewing. It is usually attached to the resource so you won;t have to load it.

Comment: I doubt this code will work without 'global $user', also it is not a good idea to use global variable $user to store data.

Comment: And if you want to show author picture in the post, better try to load the node.

Comment: would you guys please show me an example ? or kind of a code ?